# Show that $f(z)=x^3+ i(1-y)^3$ is differentiable only at $z=i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Here's the exact phrasing of the question:

Show that when $f(z)=x^3+i(1-y)^3$, where $z=x+iy$. it is legitimate to write: $$f'(z)=u_x+iv_x=3x^2$$
*only* when $z=i$

**Here's my best attempt**

We have $u=x^3$ so $u_x=3x^2$ and $u_y=0$
Also, $v=(1-y)^3$ so $v_x=0$ and $v_y=-3(1-y)^2$

By the Cauchy Reimman equations we know that the function is differentiable when $u_y=-v_x$ which is true for all $z$, however considering $u_x=v_y$ we have $3x^2=-3(1-y)^2$ which is true for an infinite number of complex numbers. Note that $z=i$ does in fact satisfy that equation. So what exactly did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $i=x_0+iy_0$, with $x_0=0$ and $y_0=1$. Now by Cauchy Riemann 
\begin{equation}
u_x=v_y \Longleftrightarrow 3x^2=-3(1-y)^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Hence equation (1) hold if $x_0+iy_0=i$, since
$$
0=3x_0^2=-3(1-y_0)^2=0
$$
thus indeed $z=i$ is a point where $f$ is differentiable. Now you have to prove that it is the only one and it is easy to do it from equation (1)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x$ and $y$ are $\textbf{real}$ numbers, so $3x^2=-3(1-y)^2$ has a solution only if $x=0$.

Comment: oh right completely overlooked that - sign over there. Thanks for pointing that out